# Unable to send message from API Gateway to FIFO SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs

I have integrated a API Gateway with FIFO SQS queue using below link
https://medium.com/@pranaysankpal/aws-api-gateway-proxy-for-sqs-simple-queue-service-5b08fe18ce50

Below is the snippet of role policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sqs:SendMessageBatch",
                "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
                "sqs:SendMessage"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:*:12345678:Stg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Whenever is try to test it from API Gateway it throws below error:-
`"Message": "The request must contain the parameter MessageGroupId."`

So I tried to send it via query string but still the error persist.

I have followed the same steps as per the above link for body template and header.

```
MessageGroupId=098
```

Simply passing above value in query string and body is below

```
{"ty":"ui"}
```

Comment: Can you put the whole code you are using?

Comment: There is no code. My Api Gateway is unable to send message to SQS wit the provided error:- ```"Message": "The request must contain the parameter MessageGroupId."```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add `MessageGroupId`, and `MessageDeduplicationId` to the **URL Query String Parameters** in **Method Execution**. Same way you did for `MessageBody`.

You'll also need to add `MessageGroupId`, and `MessageDeduplicationId` to **Integration Request**. Again the same way you did with `MessageBody`.

Comment: Body template will be. Action=SendMessage&MessageGroupId=$input.params('MessageGroupId')&MessageDeduplicationId=$input.params('MessageDeduplicationId')&MessageBody=$input.body

Answer (score 5):

You can extract the `MessageGroupId` and `MessageDeduplicationId` from the response of API gateway. eg: if the payload is something like below, you can extract the any properties from the payload.
Clear video tutorial here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXa9KA-G9Dg

Assume the payload is like this:

```
{
  "data" :{
    "jobNumber": "123456"
  }
}
```

Then the template in api gateway is below. It extract the `jobNumber` from the payload and set to `MessageGroupId`. Here the `MessageDeduplicationId` is   getting from the context.

```
#set($dedupId = $context.requestId)
#set($groupId = $input.json('$.data.jobNumber'))
Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=$input.body&MessageGroupId=$groupId&MessageDeduplicationId=$dedupId
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.